# Does Java Set<String> contains() check for existence of StringBuilder?

Tags: java, set, contains, stringbuilder

Does Java Set `contains()` know how to check for the existence of StringBuilder?

I am running this problem in Leetcode. "Find Unique Binary String". Note this Question is not about Solving the Leetcode, but understanding why an issue occurs. https://leetcode.com/problems/find-unique-binary-string/description/

> Given an array of strings nums containing n unique binary strings each
> of length n, return a binary string of length n that does not appear
> in nums. If there are multiple answers, you may return any of them.

nums  = ["00","01"]

**Code Output**
"00"

**Expected Answers Choice
"10"**

**Problem:**

This code fails at `!currentResults.contains(currentString)` where currentString is "00" ,when the number exists in the Set.

Changing it to `!currentResults.contains(currentString.toString()))` will make it succeed. I am trying to understand reason behind this.

**Code:**

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> currentResults = new HashSet<>();
String finalString;
int numsLength;

public String findDifferentBinaryString(String[] nums) {
    
    for (String data: nums) {
        currentResults.add(data);
    }
    if (nums.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    numsLength = nums.length;
    getDFS(nums, new StringBuilder(""));
    return finalString;
}

public void getDFS(String[] nums, StringBuilder currentString) {
    if (finalString != null ) {
        return;
    }

    if (currentString.length() == numsLength && !currentResults.contains(currentString)) {
        finalString = currentString.toString();
        return;
    }

    if (currentString.length() == numsLength) return;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        currentString.append(String.valueOf(i));
        getDFS(nums,currentString);
        currentString.deleteCharAt(currentString.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Java Set Contains() know how to check for existence of Stringbuilder?

No, [`Set.contains(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) checks for the existence of an Object that equals.

Quoting:

> Returns `true` if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this set contains an element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

This means that a `StringBuilder` type will not satisfy the `.equals()` clause because it will call `String.equals()` and `StringBuilder` will not satisfy a true condition without explicitly calling `.toString()` first.

There are other cases in the Java language where `.toString()` is implicitly called, but the `.equals()` operator for `String` is not one of those cases.

> (comment) I was hoping it would match set type and give a warning if `String` type does not match with `StringBuilder`

Some code editors -- such as IntelliJ -- will try to warn about this, see attached picture:

> [image]

Comment: @tresf not unfortunate, fortunate. And impossible to do otherwise as it's impossible to know in advance what something may be turned in the future.

Comment: also, by the way, removing the extra methods, and just running the simple 4 line code by itself in sequence, will not fail,  something with my for loop, dfs, array, and extra method, causes this, probably a memory reference issue too

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` are mutable and so the `equals` and `hashcode` are not overridden in both. So when someone calls the `equals` method on these references it would internally use `==` for comparison, which means only the addresses will be checked and not the content.

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("ABC");
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("ABC");

System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb2));
```

Even though both are having the same value, the output will be `false` because both references are pointing to a different memory location. So the important and primary thing to understand is that the `equals` method in `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` will not check for content.

In the case of a `Set`, the `contains()` method would be internally using `equals` and `hashcode` to check for existence. Now, if the object is of type `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` the `equals` would compare the addresses of the contents in the Set and the argument of the `contains()` method.

So, when we get into your example at this line `currentResults.contains(currentString)` won't work as you expected, because the `Set` will be calling `equals` on the `currentString` which is a StringBuilder. It will be something like this

```
currentString.equals(someElementInSet)
```

And definitely, both `currentString` and elements in the Set are in different memory locations and would return false.

Now when you call `currentResults.contains(currentString.toString()))`, the value of `currentString` gets converted to a `String` type in which `equals` method checks for content rather than the memory location. So, in this case, if currentString is **00**, the `contains()` will return true.

**Areas you can improve**

Do the length check of `nums` at the beginning of the method, you don't have to run a loop if it is empty.

Comment: Doesn't this answer assume `.equals()` is being called on `StringBuilder`, and not `String`?  Although this is valuable information, in regards to `Set<String>`, I do not believe it applies unless the example is modified to use `Set<StringBuidler>`.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, as this is contrary to some framework methods which utilize the *Object* parameter.
In these cases, they are extrapolating the *StringBuilder* through *String#valueOf*.

The difference is that the *Collections Framework* is simply disseminating the object type, and not the content.

> *"Does Java Set contains() know how to check for the existence of StringBuilder? ...*
>
> ... Changing it to `!currentResults.contains(currentString.toString()))` will make it succeed. I am trying to understand reason behind this. ..."

You're implying that *Set#contains* should interpret the content of *StringBuilder*—i.e., *currentString.toString()*.

This isn't the case.  It's just comparing the object type.

Here is the code, ultimately executed by *HashSet#contains*.
*[GitHub – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L573)*